# Transform ARRAY STRUCT Json to CSV

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

What is the solution for described: I have a parquete table that contains arrays and structs.

```
root
 |-- Loaded: long (nullable = true)
 |-- article: string (nullable = true)
 |-- brand: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uRL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- breadcrumbs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uRL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- characteristics: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- competitorKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- descriptionFull: string (nullable = true)
 |-- groupId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- groupedProducts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- keywords: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- labels: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- merchant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- extraId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isNaturalPerson: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legalAddress: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legalINN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legalName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legalOGRN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- phone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ratingCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uRL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- merchants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- questionsCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
 |-- ratingCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reviewsCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sold2M: long (nullable = true)
 |-- taskId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uRL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- variations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- article: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- barcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fbs: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- images: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- inventory: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isExpress: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isbn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- msrp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- multiProduct: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- offers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- otherSellers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- promo: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- size: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- skuId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sold: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uRL: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- videos: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- viewsCount: long (nullable = true)
```

I need to prepare the csv file from this.
The required fields are "region, id, article, name, url, variations(msrp, price, brand,breadcrumbs), merchant(id, name, legalName. legalINN, legalOGRN, phone), rating, ratingCount, reviewsCount, questionsCountr, viersCount, sold2M"

I know how to df.select("region") for example, but I do not know how to read msrp, price from "variations" array and all from "brand" struct and other cases, when columns are inside array/struct.

How can I transform this data? Thank you!
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFYWx.png)

I have tried

```
df = df.select('region','id', 'article', 'name', 'url', F.col('variations').getItem('element').getItem('msrp').cast('string'))
```

but it did not work
Error: "No such struct field element in id, skuId, uRL, article, isbn, barcode, msrp, price, promo, multiProduct, inventory, whInventories, images, videos, size, color, sold, otherSellers, properties, offers, isExpress, fbs"

Comment: `variations.mrsp` or `variations.*`?

Comment: @Lamanus variations.mrsp and variations.price